# Shiny Cards in Star Realms

Tags: star-realms

I started noticing some cards in Star Realms are sometimes shiny and animated.
https://media.giphy.com/media/YAZyFTFYc8n44J9gW9/giphy.gif

Additionally when they are purchased they spin once before going to the discard pile.
https://media.giphy.com/media/7NUwrkRQRNkNI64cS4/giphy.gif

Does this shininess indicate anything? I haven't noticed any differences in play from the non-shiny versions.

Answer (score 4):

Didn't do enough googling...

> Foil cards are premium cards with a foil finish making them
>   look shiny. They also feature minor animation that suggests motion.
>   Whether a card is foil or not has no effect on gameplay. Foils just
>   look cool. If you own a Foil Card, whenever you acquire that card
>   during regular gameplay, both in and outside of Arena, it will turn
>   into a foil. Both you and your opponent will see it as a Foil Card
>   once you acquire it. You only need one copy of a Foil Card and then
>   every version of that card you acquire in games will appear as a Foil
>   Card. You may only win one copy of each weekly and seasonal Foil Card
>   (because you only need one).

Source: https://www.starrealms.com/arena-tournament-play-foil-cards-and-united-heroes-coming-to-the-star-realms-app/